# How to remove duplicates when use full join and have null values in cells

Tags: sql-server, join, null, duplicates

This is my basic table:

> number            |SITE_WT    |SITE_WT_DATA   |SITE_NWT   |SITE_NWT_DATA A
>   |1            |NULL           |1          |NULL

and this is my select and full joins:

```
 SELECT      Number,T1.site ,T2.site,T3.site ,T4.site   
     FROM [A] AS T1
     FULL JOIN [B] AS T2
        ON T1.number=T2.number  
     FULL JOIN [C] AS T3
        ON  T2.number = T3.number  
     FULL JOIN [D] AS T4
        ON T3.number=T4.number
```

This is the result :

> number  |SITE_WT  |SITE_WT_DATA   |SITE_NWT   |SITE_NWT_DATA   A     |1234
>   |NULL         |NULL       |NULL   A     |NULL     |NULL           |1234
>   |NULL

I have the problem with **Null** and it break my **join** and i have duplicates, because the correct result  must be, only one row for every different number,Any suggestions how to  do it

Correct result :

> number  |SITE_WT  |SITE_WT_DATA   |SITE_NWT   |SITE_NWT_DATA   A     |1234
>   |NULL         |1234       |NULL

Comment: Why use full join and not inner?? Also if number exists on all tables your select is ambiguous, should not run

Comment: @kalkov please check posted answer is useful or need to do any modifications

Comment: I am new in sql and my mentor told me that i need  FULL JOIN not INNER, and it work correct when i have normal values not NULL

Comment: @Kalkov basing on your data we can guide you but in table level it's upto you how to do joins and get the data but what we answer is to get the exact output

Comment: @mohan111  Thank you! Now i will test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using MAX()

```
 SELECT      Number,MAX(T1.site) SITE_WT,MAX(T2.site)SITE_WT_DATA,MAX(T3.site)SITE_NWT ,MAX(T4.site) SITE_NWT_DATA  
         FROM [A] AS T1
         FULL JOIN [B] AS T2
            ON T1.number=T2.number  
         FULL JOIN [C] AS T3
            ON  T2.number = T3.number  
         FULL JOIN [D] AS T4
            ON T3.number=T4.number 
            GROUP BY Number
```